# Loop: Incomplete assignation of date type variable

Tags: r

I'm trying to assign the 'date' of the previous case to a new variable call "LastTripDate", as long as the IDs are the same.

The "datetime" variable has is of class POSIXlc and has the form (%Y-%M-%D %h:%m:%s). Unfortunately my loop below only returns the seconds, not the whole information.

```
  for (i in 2:length(All1[,1]))
  {
    if(as.numeric(All1$ID[i] == All1$ID[i-1]))
      {
      All1$LastTripDate1[i] <- as.Date.character(All1$datetime[i-1])
      }
    else {
    All1$LastTripDate[i] == '100'}
  }
```

Thanks!

Comment: See, for example, the `shift` function in `data.table`

Comment: When trying to apply shift to a POSIXlc variable, it doesn't return the full date information of one case. For example, B<-(shift(All1$datetime, n=1,type="lag")) would give me B[1] equal to a list of all the seconds in the column datetime, B[2] a list of the minutes, etc.

Comment: oh I see. that's not a typo. I thought you meant `POSIXct`. Why are you not using `POSIXct`?

Comment: POSIXct seems to solve the problem. Thanks!